# TensorFlowTTS is not friendly with versions TensorFlow2.8 and higher?

Tags: tensorflow

Numerous examples, including those on the forum, suggest installing TensorFlowTTS with the following command:
`import os os.system("rm -rf TensorFlowTTS") !git clone https://github.com/TensorSpeech/TensorFlowTTS.git os.chdir("TensorFlowTTS") !pip install . os.chdir("..") import sys sys.path.append("TensorFlowTTS/")`

I get an error:
`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu==2.7.0 (from tensorflowtts) (from versions: 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.9.0rc0,  2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3, 2.10.0rc0, 2.10.0rc1, 2.10.0rc2, 2.10.0rc3, 2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.11.0rc0, 2.11.0rc1, 2.11.0rc2, 2.11.0, 2.12.0)  ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu==2.7.0`

Google Collab defaults to tensorflow 2.12. Attempts to lower the version to 2.8 did not give any results. And the version 2.6 recommended in the TensorFlowTTS documentation does not allow to be installed by the colab.
Can someone advise a solution?
But it is important that the solution goes on Google's colobarator, and not on the local machine. There are many language models to be trained.

In addition to downgrading tensorflow to 2.8, I downgraded tensorflow-gpu, this reduced the errors but still did not allow the package to be successfully installed:
`error: subprocess-exited-with-error

```
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Building wheel for numba (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for numba`
```